# помогите правильно написать vbs скрипт для авторизации на сайте

Tags: vbscript

Подскажите как в скрипте vbs сделать нажатие кнопки "Вход"

вот код с страницы авторизации:

```
 <div id="divLogin">
        <table>
            <tr><th style="width:50%; text-align:right">Имя пользователя</th><td style="width:50%"><input id="tb_username" onkeypress="RestrikeSymbolInput(event,'@\\')" style="width:98%" /></td></tr>
            <tr><th style="text-align:right">Пароль</th><td><input id="tb_password" type="password" style="width:98%" onkeypress="if((event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which)==13) LoginClickAction();" /></td></tr>
            <tr><th style="text-align:right">Домен</th><td><select id="ddl_domains" style="width:98%" ></select></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align:left"><input type="checkbox" id="chb_persistent" /><label for="persistent" onclick = "document.all.chb_persistent.checked = !document.all.chb_persistent.checked">Сохранять пароль</label></td></tr>
            <tr><th></th><td><input class="button_default" type="button" value="Вход" onclick="LoginClickAction()" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="button_default" type="button" value="Отмена" onclick="hideLogin()" /></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Заполнить логин и пароль получается а вот отослать их нет, мой код:

```
Dim login_field : Set login_field = oIE.document.getElementById("tb_username") 
Dim password_field : Set password_field = oIE.document.getElementById("tb_password")
login_field.value="123" ' логин
password_field.value="123" ' пароль
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim tb_username : Set tb_username = oIE.document.getElementById("tb_username") 
Dim tb_password : Set tb_password = oIE.document.getElementById("tb_password")
Dim form_submit : Set form_submit = oIE.document.forms(0)
tb_username.value="123" ' логин
tb_password.value="123" ' пароль
form_submit.Submit 'Отсылает данные
```

Думаю так

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim submit : Set submit = oIE.document.getElementsByClassName("button_default") 
submit.Click()
```

Или, если не работает, так:

```
Dim submit : Set submit = oIE.document.getElementsByClassName("button_default") 
submit.Submit()
```